# Change Text From Listview if Clicked

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, textview

i need help here.
Lets say that I have a listview taken from database :

```
-- car

-- refrigerator

-- pencil

-- motorcycle
```

This is what i want. When i clicked at car or other option, it will change to broken.

```
-- broken

-- refrigerator

-- pencil

-- motorcycle
```

I used this before

```
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3)
 {
     TextView mTextView = (TextView) arg1;
     mTextView.setText("broken");    
     //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), data.get(arg2).toString(),3000).show();
 }});
```

the problem is when i use back button and go to that page again, it will be back like before....

Any idea ?????

Here is my full code

```
package com.test.first;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Listview extends Activity
{
SQLiteDatabase mydb;
ListView lv;
ArrayList data;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{ 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_listview);

//=====CODE FOR SHOWING THE DATA IN TOAST  =======
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3)
 {
     TextView mTextView = (TextView) arg1;
     mTextView.setText(data.get(arg2) + " has been bought !");


     //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), data.get(arg2).toString(),3000).show();
 }});

mydb = Listview.this.openOrCreateDatabase("My", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
mydb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS list (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,list varchar);");

data = new ArrayList();
//=VIEW BUTTON TO SHOW DATA INSERTED IN THE LISTVIEW=======       
Cursor cursor2=mydb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM LIST;", null);

if (cursor2.moveToFirst())
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Shop List", 3000).show();
    data.clear();
    do
    {
        data.add(cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex("list")));
    }
    while (cursor2.moveToNext());

//====CODE FOR SHOWING DATA AS A SIMPLE LIST ITEM=========================================
    ArrayAdapter <String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>      (Listview.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,data);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

}
else
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DATA NOT AVAILABLE", 3000).show();
}
cursor2.close();
}
}
```

Comment: If you are taking the items in the listView from a database, then you should also update the database upon clicking an item. If you don't, your application will just get the data from the database (original ones) and show you those, and not the edited one that you did.

Comment: which type of adapter you're using

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of that. That's why i need some solution to update only a single line of the database from the listview

Comment: This is my adpater : ArrayAdapter <String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>      (Listview.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,data);
  lv.setAdapter(adapter);

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you press the back button and then reopen the activity the ListView is recreated with the original information. This information is not changed and contains the Car text thus is normal that the ListView containts car text other time.
You shall to update your List information and then call to modify the ListView:

```
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

If you change the information and then press back and reopen the Activty the ListView will be ok.

Comment: Do you have any references like the example or the tutorial about the step how to do this ??? Thx b4

Comment: just after updating the data you may call it

Comment: @CharlesLynch i can't search references to indicate how Android works. Perhaps this is enought for you   http://i.stack.imgur.com/LXnx7.png   

When you press back button and go to other Activity the current pass for the onPause state. When return, pass for the onResume method and its resume. Your adapter shall to call other time to the method getView where your List items are recycled or created. In both methods the information is taken and put on the text view again.